# jQuery - using methods for custom events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom jQuery event like this

```js
jQuery(this).trigger({
    type: 'my_own_event',
    data1: 'foo',
    data2: 'bar'
});
```

To attach an event handler I have to use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function like this.

```js
jQuery(element).on( 'my_own_event', function(e) {
    //Do something
});
```

How do I use it like any other inbuilt event like `.click()`, `.keyup()`. Something like this

```js
jQuery(element).my_own_event(function(e){
    //Do Something
});
```

I tried using `jQuery.fn` to do this as follows

```js
jQuery.fn.my_own_event = function(callback) {
    jQuery(this).on('my_own_event',callback);
}
```

and it does work on Firefox 27.

Is this the right way to do this?

Is it OK to use underscores in the event name?

Comment: Is this the right way to do this?: Yes it is

Is it OK to use underscores in the event name? It is a matter of preference, if you ask me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine. The naming is okay, merely a matter of convention.

You should tweak the shortcut function, though. The `jQuery()` is not required, as `this` is already a `jQuery` object. You should also return the original object for chaining purposes.

You may also want to handle the empty argument version of the call, as the builtin event shortcuts do, to trigger the event.

Here's how the jQuery source itself does it:

```
jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
    return arguments.length > 0 ?
        this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
        this.trigger( name );
};
```

Where `name` is the event such as `click` or `keyup`. This also handles the optional `data` argument, which would set `event.data` in the callback function.

Then you're completely in line with the existing jQuery event shortcut function conventions.

So your example could be changed to:

```
jQuery.fn.my_own_event = function(data, callback) {
    return arguments.length > 0 ?
        this.on('my_own_event', null, data, callback) :
        this.trigger('my_own_event');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Custom event you have created is fine and the event name is also as per standard event naming convention

**Article from official Jquery site:**

*the `.trigger()` method can trigger both standard browser event names and custom event names to call attached handlers. Event names should only contain alphanumerics, underscore, and colon chraracters.*

**REF:**

https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Happy Coding:)